# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-toggle'

Tags: angular

I want to use the Angular [ng-toggle](https://github.com/nth-cloud/ng-toggle) component.

I'm using lazy loading, i'm importing the NgToggleModule in my lazy loading Module. Without the use of [(ngModule)]="cat.enable" the component renders correctly.

dispomap.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DispomapComponent } from './dispomap.component';
import { DispomapSettingsComponent } from './dispomap-settings/dispomap-settings.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DispmapService } from './Service/dispmap.service';
import { NgToggleModule } from '@nth-cloud/ng-toggle';

const routes: Routes = [
...
  {
      path: 'settings',
      data: {
          title: 'Settings'
      },
      component: DispomapSettingsComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DispomapComponent, DispomapSettingsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgToggleModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  providers: [ DispmapService ]
})
export class DispomapModule { }
```

dispomap-settings.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DispmapService } from '../Service/dispmap.service';
import { IDispoMapCategoryInfo } from '../Models/IDispoMapCategoryInfo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dispomap-settings',
  templateUrl: './dispomap-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dispomap-settings.component.scss']
})
export class DispomapSettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  CategoryInfos: IDispoMapCategoryInfo[];
  constructor(private dispomapService: DispmapService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dispomapService.GetCategories().subscribe(ci => {
      this.CategoryInfos = ci;
    });
  }

}
```

dispomap-settings.component.html

```html
<div>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let cat of CategoryInfos">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
        <ng-toggle onColor="primary" offColor="secondary" [(ngModel)]="cat.enabled"></ng-toggle>
      </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">{{cat.label}}</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">{{cat.order}}</div>
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">{{cat.trucks}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Google Chrome Console Error:

```html
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-toggle'.
1. If 'ngModel' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("yInfos">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
        <ng-toggle onColor="primary" offColor="secondary" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="cat.enabled"></ng-toggle>
      </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">{{cat.label}}</di"): ng:///DispomapModule/DispomapSettingsComponent.html@3:58
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-toggle'.
1. If 'ngModel' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("yInfos">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-1">
        <ng-toggle onColor="primary" offColor="secondary" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="cat.enabled"></ng-toggle>
      </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-4">{{cat.label}}</di"): ng:///DispomapModule/DispomapSettingsComponent.html@3:58
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:20605)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:26171)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:26158)
    at compiler.js:26101
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:26101)
    at compiler.js:26011
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2421)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `FormsModule` is not part of your module.

In order to use two-way data binding in your component, you will need to  import `FormsModule` into your module.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
//.. other imports

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    // other imports    
  ]
```

Comment: Did read this in other posts but i did not connect it with my problem. Thanks for your help.